# Changing ib_logfile* directory in MySQL 8.0 by updating innodb_log_group_home_dir

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am working on a POC where I am trying to change the transaction log files in MySQL 8.0. From my findings, I think ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 are the files that I should be concerned with (Are there any other files that I should be considering ?). In order to do that, based on the instructions on [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-init-startup-configuration.html#innodb-startup-log-file-configuration) page, I am trying to do the following :

1. Stop mysql.`sudo systemctl stop mysql`
2. Add the line `innodb_log_group_home_dir = "/media/newdisk/iblogs"` in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`
3. Start mysql. `sudo systemctl start mysql`

However, this did not seem to work. The start in Step 3 is failing. 
I have tried the following but none of these helped.

- a. restarted apparmor : `sudo systemctl restart apparmor`
- b. `/media/newdisk` is where I have the external disk. I created the
  `iblogs` directory and assigned RWX(777) permissions on it.
- c. `sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /media/newdisk`
- d. I have considered moving the `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` currently in `/var/lib/mysql`(default
  datadir) to `/media/newdisk/iblogs`

Should I also consider adding an alias in the apparmor cnf ? If yes, I dont quite get what should be my alias. Some examples I have taken a look at has the entire data directory pointing to the new location as a result of which they have set the alias for `/var/lib/mysql` to the new directory. But  I am only concerned with the ib_logile*.

Tried the above approach using [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/376925/mysql-moving-ibdata-ib-logfile) solution ,but that did not work.

Comment: I thought the most important file is `ibdata1` file? If you delete `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1`, it will recreate when you start the MySQL service

Comment: ibdata1 is the table and databases. I guess it would be important if I am trying to move **data** to a different location. Instead, my focus is to move out the logs instead

Comment: ooo my bad.. I thought its data you're moving ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the link provided by [@Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin) above. 
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/beginning-apparmor-profile-development#1-overview

This is how I was able to solve the issue and successfully update just the log directory

1. Stop mySQL.
2. Stop Apparmor.
3. Add the desired directory in mysqld.cnf
4. Give permissions of the desired directory in usr.sbin.mysqld (mysql profile)
5. Start apparmor.
6. Start mySQL;

Answer (score 1):

Apparmor often disallows services like mysqld from accessing files that are not in the prescribed locations. There should be a profile file for the mysqld service, that you need to update with the new location of your ib logfiles.

The symptom may be a report in the MySQL error log that it can't open the ib log file, either because of permission problems or because the file doesn't exist. This might be confusing, because there's no reason why these should be problems, except for apparmor.

You can also try shutting down apparmor completely as a test. If you can start MySQL Server successfully while apparmor is off, this is evidence that apparmor is blocking the file access.

You might like to read about using or modifying apparmor profiles: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/beginning-apparmor-profile-development#1-overview

Comment: Thanks. But stopping apparmor and then trying to start MySQL did not work either. :(